# How I can get web performance information using geckowebbrowser C#

Tags: c#, geckofx

I Work in windows form application with geckowebbrowser to get some web performance information like Response time, ping ,latency , hits/s and size.

where 
Latency is the time between making a request and beginning to see a result.

hits/s The number of hits or requests, that are reached to the web server called as http hits. When a page request sent from the load testing tool or a browser, the sub requests such as .css, .jpg, .js, .png, .gif and .html.

Size Number of bytes for each request

The response time and ping I get them successfully using the following code

```
 protected void geckoWebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                Debug.WriteLine("Response Time " + Perf_ResponseTime);
                Debug.WriteLine("Ping " + PingTime(geckoWebBrowser1.Url.Host));
    }



     private void ReponseTimeTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Perf_ResponseTime++;
    }


    public long PingTime(string host)
    {
        try
        {
            Ping pingClass = new Ping();
            PingReply pingReply = pingClass.Send(host);
            return pingReply.RoundtripTime;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }




    private void geckoWebBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, Gecko.Events.GeckoNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
            Debug.WriteLine("Navigating==================>" + e.Uri.AbsolutePath.ToString());
            ReponseTimeTimer.Start();
        }
    }
```

the Question how I can get other information like latency,hit\s and size